# Java diamond with for statement with different letters

Tags: java, for-loop

Have to make method that will draw this diamond using at max 3 for statements. I am able to make this using for example just "*" but how am I supposed to add new letter every line using just 3 for loops, should I use char array to make this? Thanks in advance

```
    A
   BBB
  CCCCC
 DDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEE
 DDDDDDD
  CCCCC
   BBB
    A
```

This is what I can do so far:

```
 static void diamond() {
    int n= 9;
    int a=5;
    int c=1;
    int d=0;

    for(int i= 0; i<= n/2; i++){
        for(int j= 1; j<a; j++){

                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k=1; k<c; k++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for(int m= 0; m<=d; m++ ){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        c++;
        d++;

        a--;
        System.out.println();
    }
    int b=1;
    int y=3 ;
    int z= 2;


    for(int i= 0; i<n/2+1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k= 0; k<=y; k++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for(int l= 0; l<= z; l++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        z--;
        b++;
        y--;
    }

}
```

the output

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Comment: A char[] would ameliorate your problem :)

Comment: Please, show what you have done

Comment: If output is truly fixed, you can just print a few string literals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it down to 3 for loops.

```
public static String generatDiamond(int n) {
    String diamond = "";

    String spaces = ""; // used to store spaces
    String str = ""; // string to be printed every line
    char c = 'A';

    for (int i = n; i >= -n; i--) {
        // there needs to be |i| spaces, and the char needs to be printed 2 * (n - |i|) + 1 times.


        // generate spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= Math.abs(i); j ++) {
            spaces += " ";
        }
        // add first spaces
        str += spaces;

        // add chars
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2* (n - Math.abs(i)) + 1; j ++) {
            str += c;
        }
        // add last spaces
        str += spaces;

        // add the line to the general shape
        diamond += str + "\n";

        // clear variable
        str = ""; spaces = "";

        // change the char
        if (i > 0)
            c++;
        else
            c--;
    }

    // shape is done, return it
    return diamond;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    // testing sizes 0 to 10
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("n = " + i);
        System.out.println(generatDiamond(i));
    }

}
```

Sample output:

```
    n = 0
A

n = 1
 A 
BBB
 A 

n = 2
  A  
 BBB 
CCCCC
 BBB 
  A  

n = 3
   A   
  BBB  
 CCCCC 
DDDDDDD
 CCCCC 
  BBB  
   A   

n = 4
    A    
   BBB   
  CCCCC  
 DDDDDDD 
EEEEEEEEE
 DDDDDDD 
  CCCCC  
   BBB   
    A    

n = 5
     A     
    BBB    
   CCCCC   
  DDDDDDD  
 EEEEEEEEE 
FFFFFFFFFFF
 EEEEEEEEE 
  DDDDDDD  
   CCCCC   
    BBB    
     A     

n = 6
      A      
     BBB     
    CCCCC    
   DDDDDDD   
  EEEEEEEEE  
 FFFFFFFFFFF 
GGGGGGGGGGGGG
 FFFFFFFFFFF 
  EEEEEEEEE  
   DDDDDDD   
    CCCCC    
     BBB     
      A      

n = 7
       A       
      BBB      
     CCCCC     
    DDDDDDD    
   EEEEEEEEE   
  FFFFFFFFFFF  
 GGGGGGGGGGGGG 
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
 GGGGGGGGGGGGG 
  FFFFFFFFFFF  
   EEEEEEEEE   
    DDDDDDD    
     CCCCC     
      BBB      
       A       

n = 8
        A        
       BBB       
      CCCCC      
     DDDDDDD     
    EEEEEEEEE    
   FFFFFFFFFFF   
  GGGGGGGGGGGGG  
 HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH 
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
 HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH 
  GGGGGGGGGGGGG  
   FFFFFFFFFFF   
    EEEEEEEEE    
     DDDDDDD     
      CCCCC      
       BBB       
        A        

n = 9
         A         
        BBB        
       CCCCC       
      DDDDDDD      
     EEEEEEEEE     
    FFFFFFFFFFF    
   GGGGGGGGGGGGG   
  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH  
 IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII 
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
 IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII 
  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH  
   GGGGGGGGGGGGG   
    FFFFFFFFFFF    
     EEEEEEEEE     
      DDDDDDD      
       CCCCC       
        BBB        
         A         

n = 10
          A          
         BBB         
        CCCCC        
       DDDDDDD       
      EEEEEEEEE      
     FFFFFFFFFFF     
    GGGGGGGGGGGGG    
   HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH   
  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  
 JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ 
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
 JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ 
  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  
   HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH   
    GGGGGGGGGGGGG    
     FFFFFFFFFFF     
      EEEEEEEEE      
       DDDDDDD       
        CCCCC        
         BBB         
          A
```

Comment: Thank you! First one was enough, I think I got it

Answer (score 0):

There can me several different solution.. with some slightest change in your code You can do the following

```
    static void diamond() {
    int n = 9;
    int a = 5;
    int c = 1;
    int d = 0;

    char p = 'A'; // defining a char.. instead of * we will print this

    for (int i = 0; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < a; j++) {

            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < c; k++) {
            System.out.print(p);
        }

        for (int m = 0; m <= d; m++) {
            System.out.print(p);
        }

        c++;
        d++;
        p++; // in means p will be the next char
        a--;
        System.out.println();
    }
    int b = 1;
    int y = 3;
    int z = 2;

    p--; // p will be the previous char
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2 + 1; i++) {
        p--;
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= y; k++) {
            System.out.print(p);
        }

        for (int l = 0; l <= z; l++) {
            System.out.print(p);
        }
        System.out.println();
        z--;
        b++;
        y--;
    }

}
```